# PermissionError : [Errno 13] Permission denied.When generating payload in veil

Tags: linux, permissions, root

I have installed veil and have installed all the dependencies. But when want to generate payload I get an error that unable to create output file and

```
PermissionError : [Errno 13] Permission denied'.
```

So I logged in root that I found another error that it

> is not own by you.

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the dependency that's needed can be added by installing the `winbind` package in some cases

- > ```
  > sudo apt install winbind
  > ```
  >
  > <sub>[Source](https://github.com/Veil-Framework/Veil/issues/34)</sub>

Sometimes the above command alone does not resolve the issue and you may need to remove the `winbind` package first and then reinstall it

- > ```
  > sudo apt remove winbind
  > sudo apt install winbind
  > ```
  >
  > <sub>[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090094/wine-missing-ntlm-auth-3-0-25)</sub>

---

### Additional Steps (if needed)

If you still have trouble then. . .

1. According to the ["Unable to install dotnet40"](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/677) github post, you might be able to resolve this problem by running the [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6 (Offline Installer)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137) and allowing it to run through and reinstall and put back any missing dependencies, etc. since you are running this on Windows.
2. As mentioned by someone on [this forum post], you might be able to resolve by also installing the samba package

   - > ```
     > sudo apt install samba
     > ```